Migrate from on premise TFS 2018 to GitHub
We have a on premise Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2018 on a sever in our office. It has been running for over a decade as our source control from Visual Studio with no real issues. We are currently moving all code source control to GitHub and can find no way to migrate from the on site server to GitHub. I have looked at many many suggestions from web searches but I fail when trying to enter the url for the repository as it does not seem to exist. I have tried many combinations to navigate to a web url for any of the projects but not work (when attempting to use git tfs for the migration). Any help would be appreciated
EDIT:
Our TFS instance is running on premise. I can access all repositories on our internal network but not from the outside as we are air gapped. When i enter the url to a repo as 'http://:8080/tfs///_versionControl?path=%24%2FECHO%2F' i can only download the code as a zip, there is nowhere to create a local repo. I may be muddying the water with my explanation but i would like to take this repository, and its full check-in history, and push to a new GitHub repository to take advantage of outside teams wanting to work at the same time. We want to move from an in house (and old) TFS to cloud.

What kind of source control are you using?  TFVC repo or Git repo? Can you share more details about what you have tried and the error information?

Using on site VS TFS 2018 as repo, trying to move to GitHub. No errors, other than it cannot find the original repo in TFS to move it to GitHub. I think I understand its because it is not a repo? As in its not a repo that can be exporeted easily but I guess thats why im here.

Can you help us confirm the source control type? Git repo or TFVC Repo on TFS 2018. TFS 2018 is a On-Prem Server. It is not be able to accessed by github directly. You need to command clone the repo to local machine and push it to github.

On the other hand, can you share more details about this issue I fail when trying to enter the url for the repository as it does not seem to exist. ?

Added edit with some more info

From your updated info, the repo should be a TFVC repo. To meet your requirements, you need to use git tfs tool to do the migration. You can refer to the steps in the answer.

From your updated description, you are using the TFVC repo in TFS2018. When you download the repo as zip, it will not contains the history and not show as a valid git repo.
To meet your requirement, you need to use git tfs tool to migrate the TFVC Repo to Github git repo.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Run the script: git tfs clone <TFS URL> $/project/folder (The repo type is tfvc). Then you could clone the project and all history.
Step2: Run cd repo path to navigate to the local repo path and git checkout -b customBranch   to create a temp branch.
Step3: Run git remote add origin <Git URL> to set the target.
For example: git remote add origin http://github.com.... (The repo type is git)
Step4: Run git push --set-upstream origin CustomBranch to push all repos to the temp branch.
In this case, the migrated git repo will contain all history of the tfvc repo.
Note: You need to execute the git tfs command on the machine which can connect to the TFS Server.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: importing a team foundation version control repository

What would the $/project/folder be? Where would this folder exist? I think this is what is blocking me as Ive tried to run this command without success. I am not working on the server, I am on my desktop but connected to it. Thank you for the help!

Used the documentation you linked to and after a couple small issues it worked flawlessly. Thanks for your help Kevin!!
